# How to determine validation process of a certificate used by a website using HTTPS?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser, validation

When visiting a website that uses HTTPS, we can see its certificate in the browser. 
But how can we know for sure which validation process the company or domain behind the website has gone through?

Validation processes: OV (Organization Validation), DV (Domain Validation) and EV (Extended Validation).

When I check a website's certificate details in a browser, I can't find any information about its validation process. I assumed this piece of information would be normally included in the certificate details as it would mean how much a user can trust a website they are visiting.

Comment: It's generally in the `certificate policies`.  If you look at the cert for security.stackexchange.com  (which is issued by Lets Encrypt) in your browser, and scroll down to `certificate policies`, you will see `Policy
Certificate Type ( 2.23.140.1.2.1 ); Value
Domain Validation`

Comment: @mti2935 but I don't see that in my browser, Edge https://imgur.com/a/mnybzRf

Comment: I don't use Edge, but here is how Firefox displays it:  https://imgur.com/a/3jzFNNV

Comment: You can also use a command line tool such as openssl to view information about a site's certificate; or you can use a service such as ssllabs to scan a site, and show information about a site's certificate.

Comment: @mti2935 thank you, just found an extension that shows validation process on the browser toolbar
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/certificate-info/jhldepncoippkjgjkmambfglddmjdmaj
 . apparently there is a 4th type of validation called Identity validation "IV".